# Need One Result to Be Found Using A Different WHERE. A SELECT within a SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT a.WEEK_ID, a.QUANTITY, a.PRICE AS expenseTotal, 
b.ID, b.COMMENCE, b.USER_ID,b.*, 
c.ID AS userid, c.NAME, c.LAST_NAME 
from b_sale_basket a 
INNER JOIN b_report_week b ON a.WEEK_ID = b.ID 
INNER JOIN b_user c ON b.USER_ID = c.ID 
WHERE a.ORDER_ID = $ID AND a.PRODUCT_ID = 316
```

You will see this section on the top line:

```
a.PRICE AS expenseTotal
```

I am wanting a.PRICE to be found WHERE a.PRODUCT_ID = 317 NOT 316 as it currently is.

I have tried to do a SELECT statement within a SELECT:

```
  SELECT a.WEEK_ID, a.QUANTITY, 
 (SELECT PRICE FROM b_sale_basket WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 317 AND ORDER_ID = $ID) AS expenseTotal, 
  b.ID, b.COMMENCE, b.USER_ID,b.*, 
  c.ID AS userid, c.NAME, c.LAST_NAME from b_sale_basket a 
  INNER JOIN b_report_week b ON a.WEEK_ID = b.ID 
  INNER JOIN b_user c ON b.USER_ID = c.ID 
  WHERE a.ORDER_ID = $ID AND a.PRODUCT_ID = 316
```

But that's not worked.  Please could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You really couldn't be more cryptic in your wording.

Comment: Really sorry, I will try and reword it.

Comment: Is `php` code really relevant for this question? Why not just focus on the `SQL` query? Can you clean up the unnecessary stuff from the Q?

Comment: You have too many end paranthesis in the second SQL statement.

Comment: I'm confused, why cant you just change it to 317? And why is it 316?

Comment: I am using it in a while loop within PHP and it returns the relevant rows, I need to use $row['expenseTotal'] as a variable within the row.

Comment: why not do a SUM() on all products and remove PRODUCT_ID = 317 from the sub select?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another JOIN

Something like:

```
SELECT a.WEEK_ID, a.QUANTITY, 
 d.PRICE AS expenseTotal, 
  b.ID, b.COMMENCE, b.USER_ID,b.*, 
  c.ID AS userid, c.NAME, c.LAST_NAME 
  FROM b_sale_basket a 
  INNER JOIN b_report_week b ON a.WEEK_ID = b.ID 
  INNER JOIN b_user c ON b.USER_ID = c.ID 
  INNER JOIN b_sales_basket d ON d.ORDER_ID = a.ORDER_ID AND d.PRODUCT_ID = 317
  WHERE a.ORDER_ID = $ID AND a.PRODUCT_ID = 316
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't return anything.  I see what you're trying to do but it just doesn't show any result.

Comment: well, that's why I said 'like' this. Just play around with it and I'm sure you'll get what youre looking for, I just went with your sub select.
If ORDER_ID is your primary key then of course it won't return anything since its impossible for one row to have two values for PRODUCT_ID